# SQLite Queries for dates

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a SQLite data base which I am pulling data for a specific set of dates (lets say 01-01-2011 to 01-01-2011). What is the best way to implement this query into SQL. Ideally I would like the following line to run:

SELECT * FROM database where start_date < date_stamp and end_date > date_stamp

This obviously does not work when I store the dates as strings.

My solution (which I think is messy and I am hoping for another one) is to convert the dates into integers in the following format:
YYYYMMDD
Which makes the above line able to run (theoretically). IS there a better method?

Using python sqlite3

Would the answer be any different if I were using SQL not SQLite

Answer (score 0):

For SQLlite it is the best approach, as comparison with int much faster than strings or any [Date And Time](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) manipulations

Answer (score 0):

You should store the dates in one of the [supported date/time datatypes](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#datetime), then comparisons will work without conversions, and you would be able to use the [built-in date/time functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) on them.
(Whether you use strings or numbers does not matter for speed; database performance is mostly determined by the amount of I/O needed.)

In other SQL databases that have a built-in date datatype, you could use that.
(However, this is usually not portable.)